# Firebase : Why appearing [clound_firestore/permission-denied] for my firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know there is a lot of similar posts, but I still cannot find my own answer for my issue. Since I want to get the data from firebase without pressing the button and diretly can get the data from it, therefore I have used the StreamBuilder for my coding but I still get this error. Is this is my firestore database or realtime database permission get any wrong?

--Issue warning--

[image]

Below are my coding:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:profile_staff/edit_profile_page.dart';
import 'package:profile_staff/profile_widget.dart';
import 'package:profile_staff/user.dart';
import 'package:profile_staff/user_preferences.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> users =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = UserPreferences.myUser;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
            onPressed: () {}, icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp)),
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'My Profile',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditProfilePage()),
                );
              },
              icon: new Icon(Icons.create_outlined))
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        shadowColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 3,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Read Data',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 250,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: users,
                  builder: (
                    BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
                  ) {
                    // if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    //   return Text('error404');
                    // }
                    
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text('Loading');
                    }

                    final data = snapshot.requireData;

                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.size,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text(
                            'My name is ${data.docs[index]['name']} and I am ${data.docs[index]['age']}');
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
       
}
```

My Firestore Database:

[image]

[image]

My Realtime Database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTk3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxq0D.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you are pointing to same DB?

Comment: I am no sure about it, because this is my first time to use firebase in flutter. Did I really use wrong DB in my coding?

Comment: Your security rules requires that the user is signed in to Firebase Authentication to be able to access the database. Since the rules reject the read operation, it seems that the user is not signed in. I recommend having a look at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.Forgot to deploy/upload new rules

Comment: Same issue? You mean my DB rule got wrong but I also dont know how to edit? I also try chance the rule based on the material from internet but still no work.